# refresh page after change checkbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, checkbox

How is it possible to refresh a page/checkbox after changing the value via javascript.
My App reads a boolean value from the localstorage and check or uncheck the checkbox.

```
$('#settingsContent').trigger("create");
$('#settingsContent').page();
```

Tried this two ways but it doesn't work. Only with the page() Methode i get a white page.
Only with trigger("create") nothing happens.

```
<div id="settingsContent">
```

Is the name of my div tag.

It is a phonegap app using jquery html etc..

***EDIT***

```
valueVar = document.getElementById(nameVar);
if (timeStamp == true) {
         valueVar.checked = true;
    } else {
         valueVar.checked = false;
    }
```

timeStamp is a value from my localstorage. 
This work's. But after this code i check or uncheck my checkbox. It work's also. 
I need not refresh the page? To see the checked checkboxes?

Comment: Do we have method `.page()` in jQuery?

Comment: You want to change checkbox value after change or reload page?

Answer (score 7):

You want to reload your page after CheckBox content change?

```
$('#checkbox').on('change', function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: No not directly, i change the value of my checkbox via javascript. so i want reload the my checkbox. with the new value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use load of JQuery if you want to load only partial part of you DOM

```
   $("#settingsContent).load(url);
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the HTML content of an element, you can use the following:

```
var newContent = "Hello";
$('#settingsContent').html(newContent);
```

The `html()` method will also take HTML syntax, not just a string.